# Biblatex displaying second author as first initial + last name for Chinese authors only?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

Quite puzzled by what is going on.

Biblatex consistently displays the second author as first initial + last name, but seems to do this for Chinese authors only. Which does not seem possible or logical.

For example, (1) returns `Ding and M. Zhang (2015)`, while (2) returns `Nevins and Anand (2003)`. I use the authoryear format.

Any clue of what the issue may be?

```
(1) 
@inbook{ding2015,
Author = {Jiayong Ding and Min Zhang},
Publisher = {Commercial Press},
Title = {VP patterns in Xiang dialects on the semantic map of ditransitives},
Url = {http://repository.ust.hk/ir/Record/1783.1-78869},
Year = {2015},
Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://repository.ust.hk/ir/Record/1783.1-78869}}

(2)
@inproceedings{nevinsanand2003,
Author = {Andrew Nevins and Pranav Anand},
Booktitle = {WCCFL 22 Proceedings},
Editor = {G. Garding and M. Tsujimura},
Pages = {370-383},
Publisher = {Cascadilla Press},
Title = {Some AGREEment Matters},
Year = {2003}}
```

Comment: I assume you have another author named "Zangh" in your .bib file. Am I correct?

Comment: turns out there is! and it turns out every single case happens to be like this. Thanks for the help ;p

Comment: Yes, that's `biblatex`'s name disambiguation working, which is a nice feature, actually. Having understood what it is and why it happens, do you really want to drop the initials?

Comment: nope. Was just confused because I didn't realize it needed disambiguation...

Comment: Ah, ok! That's it. Biblatex uses other parts of the name, to differentiate two authors which would be indistinguishable without it. Similar things are done for name lists. That given, should I recommend closing this question as solved in the comments?